# Two joins in mysql query not returning expected result

Tags: mysql, sql, join, resultset

I am working on a join and I cannot seem to get the resultset that I need. Let me paint the scenario:

I have 2 tables:

Data table

```
+----+-------+
| ID | Name  |
+----+-------+
| 10 | Test1 |
| 11 | Test2 |
| 12 | Test3 |
| 13 | Test4 |
| 14 | Test5 |
| 15 | Test6 |
+----+-------+
```

Join table

```
+----+-----+-----+-----+
| ID | FID | GID | Val |
+----+-----+-----+-----+
| 10 |   3 |     | abc |
| 10 |     |   1 | def |
| 11 |   3 |     | ijk |
| 12 |     |   1 | lmn |
| 13 |   4 |     | opq |
+----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Expected Result Set

```
+---------------+-----------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+
| Data table id | Data table name | Join Tabe FID | Join Table GID | Join Table Val |
+---------------+-----------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+
|            10 | Test1           |             3 |                | abc            |
|            11 | test2           |             3 |                | ijk            |
|            12 | test3           |               |              1 | lmn            |
+---------------+-----------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+
```

My Query

```
Select
   *
from
   datatable A
join jointable b
on
   A.ID = B.ID
   and B.FID = 3
join jointable c
on
   A.ID = C.ID
   and C.GID = 1
   and C.FID <> null
```

What is happening is that the join on table C is being done on the resultset of the join between table A and B, therefore the resultset is blank.

I want the join on table C to be applied on table A and not on the resultset from the join between table A and B; which will result on the expected resultset.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: There are no records with an `id` of 3, so I would expect `B.ID = 3` to filter out all records.

Comment: I think what you need is a left outer join, but I dont fully understand your question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry was a typo, corrected

Comment: @mh-dev a left outer join will return ID 13, which I do not need

Comment: can anyone explain what OP wants? I don't get it from the ex.

Comment: @ZahiroMor check Spencer7593's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36014355/439002 . Maybe it will help understand what I needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression  **`C.FID <> null`**  will never evaluate to true, it will always return NULL. An inequality comparison to `NULL` will always evaluate to `NULL`. (In SQL, in a boolean context, en expression will evaluate to one of *three* possible values: `TRUE`, `FALSE` or `NULL`.)

If you want a comparison to `NULL` to return `TRUE` or `FALSE`, use an `IS [NOT] NULL` comparison test. An expression like

```
foo IS NULL
```

or

```
foo IS NOT NULL
```

Or, you could make use the MySQL specific null-safe comparison (spaceship) operator:

```
foo <=> NULL
```

or

```
NOT (foo <=> NULL)
```

---

As to the result you want to return, it's a bit confusing as to how you arrive at what you want to return.

To me, it looks like you are wanting to get the matching rows from `jointable`... if there are matching rows with `fid=3`, return just those rows. If there aren't any matching rows with `fid=3`, then return rows that have a NULL value in `fid` and `gid=1`.

If that's what we want returned, we can write a query that does that. If that's not what we want returned, then the rest of this answer doesn't matter.

We can use a `NOT EXISTS` predicate to test for the non existence of matching rows.

For example:

```
SELECT d.id 
     , d.name
     , j.fid
     , j.gid
     , j.val
  FROM datatable d
  JOIN jointable j
    ON j.id = d.id
 WHERE ( j.fid = 3 )
    OR ( j.fid IS NULL
         AND j.gid = 1 
         AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                            FROM jointable t
                           WHERE t.id = d.id
                             AND t.fid = 3
                        )
       )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
*
FROM datatable A
LEFT JOIN jointable B ON A.ID = B.ID 
WHERE B.FID = 3 OR B.GID = 1;
```

This will return you:

```
10  Test1   10  3       abc
10  Test1   10      1   def
11  Test2   11  3       ijk
12  Test3   12      1   lmn
```

Now, it seems you want to filter out:

```
10  Test1   10  3       abc
```

and keep

```
10  Test1   10      1   def
```

Is that what you want?

Regards

Comment: Left JOIN here is unnecessary,WHERE B makes it into an INNER JOIN

Answer (score 0):

To be honest not sure if I understand what you want, so this might not be correct. What I think you want is.
You have two tables and want to join all rows from the join table where the id matches and fid= 3 or gid=1 and fid not null. The query for this should be something like this. (one join should be enough)

```
Select
   *
from
   datatable A
join jointable b
on
   A.ID = B.ID
where b.fid = 3 or (b.gid = 1 and b.fid <> null)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM   table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b ON a.ID = b.ID
WHERE b.FID = 3 OR b.GID = 1
```

But your question is not very specific as far as the WHERE clauses

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM db1 
INNER JOIN db2 ON db1.id = db2.id
WHERE db1.FID = 3 or db2.GID = 1;
```

Why do you use C.FID <> null when B.GID = 1? It should be null.